# Where is Apache Kafka placed in the PACELC-Theorem

Tags: apache-kafka, bigdata, cap-theorem

I am starting to learn about Apache Kafka. This https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/intra-cluster-replication-apache-kafka article states that Kafka is a CA system inside the CAP-Theorem. So it focuses on consistency between replicas and also on overall availability.

I recently heard about an extension of the CAP-Theorem called PACELC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PACELC_theorem).
This theorem could be visualized like this:

[image]

My question is how Apache Kafka could be described in PACELC. I would think that Kafka focuses on consistency when a partition occurs but what otherwise if no partition occurs? Is the focus on low latancy or strong consistency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would depend on your configuration.

Kafka is backed by CP ZooKeeper for operations that require strong consistency, such as controller election (which decides on partition leaders), broker registration, dynamic configs, acl-s etc.
As for the data you send to kafka - guarantees are **configurable on producer level, per-topic basis or/and change broker defaults**.

Out of the box with default config (`min.insync.replicas=1`, `default.replication.factor=1`) you are getting AP system (at-most-once).

If you want to achieve CP, you may set `min.insync.replicas=2` and topic replication factor of 3 - then producing a message with `acks=all` will guarantee CP setup (at-least-once), but (as expected) will block in cases when not enough replicas (<2) are available for particular topic/partition pair. (see [design_ha](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_ha), [producer config docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs))

Kafka pipeline can be further tuned in [exactly-once](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) direction..

**CAP and PACELC**
In terms of PACELC some latency-improving decisions were already made into defaults. For example kafka by default does not `fsync` each message to disc - it writes to pagecache and let OS to deal with flushing. Defaults prefer to use replication for durability. Its configurable as well - see `flush.messages`, `flush.ms` broker/topic configurations.

Due to generic nature of messages it receives (its just a bytestream) - it cannot do any post partition merging, or using CRDTs tricks to guaranty availability during partition, and eventually restore consistency.

I dont see/know how you can `give up` consistency for latency during `normal operation` in kafka-s **generic bytestream case**. You might give up strong consistency (linearizability) and try to have '*more consistency*' (covering a bit more failure scenarios, or reducing size of data loss), but this is effectively tuning AP system for higher consistency rather that tuning CP for lower latency.

You might see AP/CP trade offs and configurations to be presented as at-least-once vs at-most-once vs exactly-once.

**Testing**
In order to understand how this parameters affect latency - I think the best way is to **test** your setup with different params. Following command will generate 1Gb of data:

```
kafka-producer-perf-test --topic test --num-records 1000000 --record-size 100 --throughput 10000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092 acks=all`
```

Then try to use different producer params:

```
acks=1  
acks=all  
acks=1 batch.size=1000000 linger.ms=1000  
acks=all batch.size=1000000 linger.ms=1000
```

Its easy to start cluster and start/stop/kill nodes to test some failure scenarios e.g. with [compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/master/examples/enterprise-kafka/docker-compose.yml)

**Links and references**
You might check (unfortunately outdated, but still relevant to topic) [jepsen test](https://aphyr.com/posts/293-jepsen-kafka) and [follow-up](http://blog.empathybox.com/post/62279088548/a-few-notes-on-kafka-and-jepsen), just to add some context on how this was evolving over time.

I highly encourage check some papers, which will give a bit more perspective:
[A Critique of the CAP Theorem. Martin Kleppmann](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.05393)
[CAP Twelve years later: How the "Rules" have Changed. Eric Brewer](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220476881_CAP_Twelve_years_later_How_the_Rules_have_Changed)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is acks=all needed, to guarantee consistency but reduce latancy in an CP setup?

Comment: @Alex Can't you technically build a purely ops-based CRDT on top of Kafka though? Assuming you ensure that all events that end up on different partitions commute, and that the message contains all timestamp information needed that consumers/stream processors may need for causal consistency when reading messages from different partitions that are causally related